# Google pie chart very small but takes big area

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, pie-chart, google-chat

I have the following page (please look below), with Bootstrap 4 and Google chart.

There are 3 black boxes, the one at the right has the google chart pie.
The problem I have is the area used for the chart is too big compared with the actual chart.

So I configuring the chart with this size:

```
div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 500px; height: 250px;"></div>
```

but as you can see, it takes all that space, but the chart is actually half of the size of the area used by that div.

Is there any way to configure this to reduce the area used by that div, but increasing the size of the chart to use most of space 500px x 250px?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">

 <head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
            ['Work', 60],
            ['Eat', 20],
            ['Watch TV', 10],
            ['Sleep', 10]
        ]);

        var options = {
            //title: 'My Daily Activities',
            backgroundColor: '#343a40',
            colors: ['#2F5499', '#3965B8', '#708CCE', '#4A6BAD'],
            is3D: true,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
 </script>
 </head>
 </head>

   <body>

   <style>
    .card-body {
        padding: 0.01rem
    }

    .padding-header {
        padding: 0.6rem
    }

    .bg-light-blue {
        background-color: #4671C3;
    }

    .bg-lila {
        background-color: #6F339F;
    }

    .bg-dark {
        background-color: #424242;
    }

    .black-box-size {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
    }

    .shape-round {
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        background-color: #6F339F;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 3.5rem 1.5rem;
    }

    .block-container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 40%;
        left: 50%;
        -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        width: 109px;
        height: 38px;
    }
</style>
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="padding-header bg-light-blue text-white">Opportunity Breakdown (Sat)</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-11">
                    <div class="black-box-size bg-dark text-white">
                        <div>
                            <h2 class="text-center padding-header">Today</h2>
                            <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">

            <div class="black-box-size bg-dark text-white">
                <div>
                    <h2 class="text-center padding-header">This Week</h2>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-11">
                    <div class="black-box-size bg-dark text-white">
                        <div>
                            <h2 class="text-center padding-header">This Month</h2>
                            <div >

                                <div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 500px; height: 250px;"></div>


                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the response:
in the option:
chartArea: {width: 400, height: 300}

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options

Comment: How did you solve this? I didn't understand.